# convert cell segmentation results to a table of intensity values

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am trying to segment a multiplexed cell imaging dataset. You usually get a 2D array of predicted cell/nucleus labels as the result. A figure to illustrate the input and output:

[image]

The next step is to quantify the intensities for each antibody/stain for each cell. Somehow I did not see that aspect discussed in any of the tutorials. Is there a proper way of doing that?

Update: There appears to be some confusion what the data represents. In the example image, you are trying to identify individual cells. Each blob is a cell. Every cell gets a different label. The predictions are colored by label. You want to determine how bright each cell is. Here is an [example workflow](https://nbviewer.org/github/stardist/stardist/blob/master/examples/2D/3_prediction.ipynb).

Comment: Could you say a little more about the labels:   Are they per-pixel, or are you doing some sort of blob-finding and then computing an overall label for each blob?   It *appears* from the right-hand figure that the blobs are quite uniform within, but too many questions to make much of a guess.

Comment: could you elaborate/link the data? what do you mean by intensity? which tutorials are you referring to? what is the prediction here? what does the hue/color represent in the second image (prediction+input overlay)?

Comment: You could loop over each cell after connectedComponentsWithStats and compute the mean value. You might also use watershed to separate touching cells.

Comment: Sorry about that. I assumed this is a more common situation. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an [x, y] array for each label iterate over it computing the mean of bright intensities of pixels in the original image.

```
for label in array:
    intensities = []
    for coordinate in label:
        intensities.append(original_image[coordinate[0], coordinate[1]])
    cell_bright = np.mean(intensities)
    # Use or store cell_bright
```

Comment: that can be done more efficiently using numpy indexing and a mask array

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you point to an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skimage.measure.regionprops_table`.

```
import pandas as pd
from skimage import measure

res = measure.regionprops_table(label_image, intensity_image, properties = ['intensity_mean'])
resdf = pd.DataFrame(res)
```